# Not sure why moving mesh gradient isn't loading onto site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to import this mesh gradient to create a site. It should be self explanatory as I followde the steps from this [site](https://whatamesh.vercel.app/), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```js
/* reference — https://whatamesh.vercel.app/ */

import { Gradient } from './Gradient.js'
  
// Create your instance
const gradient = new Gradient()
  
// Call `initGradient` with the selector to your canvas
gradient.initGradient('#gradient-canvas')
```

```css
#gradient-canvas {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  --gradient-color-1: #c3e4ff; 
  --gradient-color-2: #6ec3f4; 
  --gradient-color-3: #eae2ff;  
  --gradient-color-4: #b9beff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>
    Portfolio
</title>

<link href="css/portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<canvas id="gradient-canvas" data-transition-in> </canvas>

</head>

    <body>

        <script src="js/mesh-gradient.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The gradient.js file could be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jordienr/64bcf75f8b08641f205bd6a1a0d4ce1d).

How to import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `<canvas id="gradient-canvas" data-transition-in> </canvas>` is not within your `<body>` tag.

```js
function normalizeColor(e){return[(e>>16&255)/255,(e>>8&255)/255,(255&e)/255]}["SCREEN","LINEAR_LIGHT"].reduce(((e,n,t)=>Object.assign(e,{[n]:t})),{});class MiniGl{constructor(e,n,t,i=!1){const s=this,o=-1!==document.location.search.toLowerCase().indexOf("debug=webgl");s.canvas=e,s.gl=s.canvas.getContext("webgl",{antialias:!0}),s.meshes=[];const r=s.gl;n&&t&&this.setSize(n,t),s.lastDebugMsg,s.debug=i&&o?function(e){const n=new Date;n-s.lastDebugMsg>1e3&&console.log("---"),console.log(n.toLocaleTimeString()+Array(Math.max(0,32-e.length)).join(" ")+e+": ",...Array.from(arguments).slice(1)),s.lastDebugMsg=n}:()=>{},Object.defineProperties(s,{Material:{enumerable:!1,value:class{constructor(e,n,t={}){const i=this;function o(e,n){const t=r.createShader(e);return r.shaderSource(t,n),r.compileShader(t),r.getShaderParameter(t,r.COMPILE_STATUS)||console.error(r.getShaderInfoLog(t)),s.debug("Material.compileShaderSource",{source:n}),t}function a(e,n){return Object.entries(e).map((([e,t])=>t.getDeclaration(e,n))).join("\n")}i.uniforms=t,i.uniformInstances=[];const l="\n              precision highp float;\n            ";i.vertexSource=`\n              ${l}\n              attribute vec4 position;\n              attribute vec2 uv;\n              attribute vec2 uvNorm;\n              ${a(s.commonUniforms,"vertex")}\n              ${a(t,"vertex")}\n              ${e}\n            `,i.Source=`\n              ${l}\n              ${a(s.commonUniforms,"fragment")}\n              ${a(t,"fragment")}\n              ${n}\n            `,i.vertexShader=o(r.VERTEX_SHADER,i.vertexSource),i.fragmentShader=o(r.FRAGMENT_SHADER,i.Source),i.program=r.createProgram(),r.attachShader(i.program,i.vertexShader),r.attachShader(i.program,i.fragmentShader),r.linkProgram(i.program),r.getProgramParameter(i.program,r.LINK_STATUS)||console.error(r.getProgramInfoLog(i.program)),r.useProgram(i.program),i.attachUniforms(void 0,s.commonUniforms),i.attachUniforms(void 0,i.uniforms)}attachUniforms(e,n){const t=this;void 0===e?Object.entries(n).forEach((([e,n])=>{t.attachUniforms(e,n)})):"array"==n.type?n.value.forEach(((n,i)=>t.attachUniforms(`${e}[${i}]`,n))):"struct"==n.type?Object.entries(n.value).forEach((([n,i])=>t.attachUniforms(`${e}.${n}`,i))):(s.debug("Material.attachUniforms",{name:e,uniform:n}),t.uniformInstances.push({uniform:n,location:r.getUniformLocation(t.program,e)}))}}},Uniform:{enumerable:!1,value:class{constructor(e){this.type="float",Object.assign(this,e),this.typeFn={float:"1f",int:"1i",vec2:"2fv",vec3:"3fv",vec4:"4fv",mat4:"Matrix4fv"}[this.type]||"1f",this.update()}update(e){void 0!==this.value&&r[`uniform${this.typeFn}`](e,0===this.typeFn.indexOf("Matrix")?this.transpose:this.value,0===this.typeFn.indexOf("Matrix")?this.value:null)}getDeclaration(e,n,t){const i=this;if(i.excludeFrom!==n){if("array"===i.type)return i.value[0].getDeclaration(e,n,i.value.length)+`\nconst int ${e}_length = ${i.value.length};`;if("struct"===i.type){let s=e.replace("u_","");return s=s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+s.slice(1),`uniform struct ${s} \n                                {\n`+Object.entries(i.value).map((([e,t])=>t.getDeclaration(e,n).replace(/^uniform/,""))).join("")+`\n} ${e}${t>0?`[${t}]`:""};`}return`uniform ${i.type} ${e}${t>0?`[${t}]`:""};`}}}},PlaneGeometry:{enumerable:!1,value:class{constructor(e,n,t,i,o){r.createBuffer(),this.attributes={position:new s.Attribute({target:r.ARRAY_BUFFER,size:3}),uv:new s.Attribute({target:r.ARRAY_BUFFER,size:2}),uvNorm:new s.Attribute({target:r.ARRAY_BUFFER,size:2}),index:new s.Attribute({target:r.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,size:3,type:r.UNSIGNED_SHORT})},this.setTopology(t,i),this.setSize(e,n,o)}setTopology(e=1,n=1){const t=this;t.xSegCount=e,t.ySegCount=n,t.vertexCount=(t.xSegCount+1)*(t.ySegCount+1),t.quadCount=t.xSegCount*t.ySegCount*2,t.attributes.uv.values=new Float32Array(2*t.vertexCount),t.attributes.uvNorm.values=new Float32Array(2*t.vertexCount),t.attributes.index.values=new Uint16Array(3*t.quadCount);for(let e=0;e<=t.ySegCount;e++)for(let n=0;n<=t.xSegCount;n++){const i=e*(t.xSegCount+1)+n;if(t.attributes.uv.values[2*i]=n/t.xSegCount,t.attributes.uv.values[2*i+1]=1-e/t.ySegCount,t.attributes.uvNorm.values[2*i]=n/t.xSegCount*2-1,t.attributes.uvNorm.values[2*i+1]=1-e/t.ySegCount*2,n<t.xSegCount&&e<t.ySegCount){const s=e*t.xSegCount+n;t.attributes.index.values[6*s]=i,t.attributes.index.values[6*s+1]=i+1+t.xSegCount,t.attributes.index.values[6*s+2]=i+1,t.attributes.index.values[6*s+3]=i+1,t.attributes.index.values[6*s+4]=i+1+t.xSegCount,t.attributes.index.values[6*s+5]=i+2+t.xSegCount}}t.attributes.uv.update(),t.attributes.uvNorm.update(),t.attributes.index.update(),s.debug("Geometry.setTopology",{uv:t.attributes.uv,uvNorm:t.attributes.uvNorm,index:t.attributes.index})}setSize(e=1,n=1,t="xz"){const i=this;i.width=e,i.height=n,i.orientation=t,i.attributes.position.values&&i.attributes.position.values.length===3*i.vertexCount||(i.attributes.position.values=new Float32Array(3*i.vertexCount));const o=e/-2,r=n/-2,a=e/i.xSegCount,l=n/i.ySegCount;for(let e=0;e<=i.ySegCount;e++){const n=r+e*l;for(let s=0;s<=i.xSegCount;s++){const r=o+s*a,l=e*(i.xSegCount+1)+s;i.attributes.position.values[3*l+"xyz".indexOf(t[0])]=r,i.attributes.position.values[3*l+"xyz".indexOf(t[1])]=-n}}i.attributes.position.update(),s.debug("Geometry.setSize",{position:i.attributes.position})}}},Mesh:{enumerable:!1,value:class{constructor(e,n){const t=this;t.geometry=e,t.material=n,t.wireframe=!1,t.attributeInstances=[],Object.entries(t.geometry.attributes).forEach((([e,n])=>{t.attributeInstances.push({attribute:n,location:n.attach(e,t.material.program)})})),s.meshes.push(t),s.debug("Mesh.constructor",{mesh:t})}draw(){r.useProgram(this.material.program),this.material.uniformInstances.forEach((({uniform:e,location:n})=>e.update(n))),this.attributeInstances.forEach((({attribute:e,location:n})=>e.use(n))),r.drawElements(this.wireframe?r.LINES:r.TRIANGLES,this.geometry.attributes.index.values.length,r.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0)}remove(){s.meshes=s.meshes.filter((e=>e!=this))}}},Attribute:{enumerable:!1,value:class{constructor(e){this.type=r.FLOAT,this.normalized=!1,this.buffer=r.createBuffer(),Object.assign(this,e),this.update()}update(){void 0!==this.values&&(r.bindBuffer(this.target,this.buffer),r.bufferData(this.target,this.values,r.STATIC_DRAW))}attach(e,n){const t=r.getAttribLocation(n,e);return this.target===r.ARRAY_BUFFER&&(r.enableVertexAttribArray(t),r.vertexAttribPointer(t,this.size,this.type,this.normalized,0,0)),t}use(e){r.bindBuffer(this.target,this.buffer),this.target===r.ARRAY_BUFFER&&(r.enableVertexAttribArray(e),r.vertexAttribPointer(e,this.size,this.type,this.normalized,0,0))}}}});const a=[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1];s.commonUniforms={projectionMatrix:new s.Uniform({type:"mat4",value:a}),modelViewMatrix:new s.Uniform({type:"mat4",value:a}),resolution:new s.Uniform({type:"vec2",value:[1,1]}),aspectRatio:new s.Uniform({type:"float",value:1})}}setSize(e=640,n=480){this.width=e,this.height=n,this.canvas.width=e,this.canvas.height=n,this.gl.viewport(0,0,e,n),this.commonUniforms.resolution.value=[e,n],this.commonUniforms.aspectRatio.value=e/n,this.debug("MiniGL.setSize",{width:e,height:n})}setOrthographicCamera(e=0,n=0,t=0,i=-2e3,s=2e3){this.commonUniforms.projectionMatrix.value=[2/this.width,0,0,0,0,2/this.height,0,0,0,0,2/(i-s),0,e,n,t,1],this.debug("setOrthographicCamera",this.commonUniforms.projectionMatrix.value)}render(){this.gl.clearColor(0,0,0,0),this.gl.clearDepth(1),this.meshes.forEach((e=>e.draw()))}}function e(e,n,t){return n in e?Object.defineProperty(e,n,{value:t,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):e[n]=t,e}class Gradient{constructor(...n){e(this,"el",void 0),e(this,"cssVarRetries",0),e(this,"maxCssVarRetries",200),e(this,"angle",0),e(this,"isLoadedClass",!1),e(this,"isScrolling",!1),e(this,"scrollingTimeout",void 0),e(this,"scrollingRefreshDelay",200),e(this,"isIntersecting",!1),e(this,"shaderFiles",void 0),e(this,"vertexShader",void 0),e(this,"sectionColors",void 0),e(this,"computedCanvasStyle",void 0),e(this,"conf",void 0),e(this,"uniforms",void 0),e(this,"t",1253106),e(this,"last",0),e(this,"width",void 0),e(this,"minWidth",1111),e(this,"height",600),e(this,"xSegCount",void 0),e(this,"ySegCount",void 0),e(this,"mesh",void 0),e(this,"material",void 0),e(this,"geometry",void 0),e(this,"minigl",void 0),e(this,"scrollObserver",void 0),e(this,"amp",320),e(this,"seed",5),e(this,"freqX",14e-5),e(this,"freqY",29e-5),e(this,"freqDelta",1e-5),e(this,"activeColors",[1,1,1,1]),e(this,"isMetaKey",!1),e(this,"isGradientLegendVisible",!1),e(this,"isMouseDown",!1),e(this,"handleScroll",(()=>{clearTimeout(this.scrollingTimeout),this.scrollingTimeout=setTimeout(this.handleScrollEnd,this.scrollingRefreshDelay),this.isGradientLegendVisible&&this.hideGradientLegend(),this.conf.playing&&(this.isScrolling=!0,this.pause())})),e(this,"handleScrollEnd",(()=>{this.isScrolling=!1,this.isIntersecting&&this.play()})),e(this,"resize",(()=>{this.width=window.innerWidth,this.minigl.setSize(this.width,this.height),this.minigl.setOrthographicCamera(),this.xSegCount=Math.ceil(this.width*this.conf.density[0]),this.ySegCount=Math.ceil(this.height*this.conf.density[1]),this.mesh.geometry.setTopology(this.xSegCount,this.ySegCount),this.mesh.geometry.setSize(this.width,this.height),this.mesh.material.uniforms.u_shadow_power.value=this.width<600?5:6})),e(this,"handleMouseDown",(e=>{this.isGradientLegendVisible&&(this.isMetaKey=e.metaKey,this.isMouseDown=!0,!1===this.conf.playing&&requestAnimationFrame(this.animate))})),e(this,"handleMouseUp",(()=>{this.isMouseDown=!1})),e(this,"animate",(e=>{if(!this.shouldSkipFrame(e)||this.isMouseDown){if(this.t+=Math.min(e-this.last,1e3/15),this.last=e,this.isMouseDown){let e=160;this.isMetaKey&&(e=-160),this.t+=e}this.mesh.material.uniforms.u_time.value=this.t,this.minigl.render()}if(0!==this.last&&this.isStatic)return this.minigl.render(),void this.disconnect();(this.conf.playing||this.isMouseDown)&&requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)})),e(this,"addIsLoadedClass",(()=>{!this.isLoadedClass&&(this.isLoadedClass=!0,this.el.classList.add("isLoaded"),setTimeout((()=>{this.el.parentElement.classList.add("isLoaded")}),3e3))})),e(this,"pause",(()=>{this.conf.playing=!1})),e(this,"play",(()=>{requestAnimationFrame(this.animate),this.conf.playing=!0})),e(this,"initGradient",(e=>(this.el=document.querySelector(e),this.connect(),this)))}async connect(){this.shaderFiles={vertex:"varying vec3 v_color;\n\nvoid main() {\n  float time = u_time * u_global.noiseSpeed;\n\n  vec2 noiseCoord = resolution * uvNorm * u_global.noiseFreq;\n\n  vec2 st = 1. - uvNorm.xy;\n\n  //\n  // Tilting the plane\n  //\n\n  // Front-to-back tilt\n  float tilt = resolution.y / 2.0 * uvNorm.y;\n\n  // Left-to-right angle\n  float incline = resolution.x * uvNorm.x / 2.0 * u_vertDeform.incline;\n\n  // Up-down shift to offset incline\n  float offset = resolution.x / 2.0 * u_vertDeform.incline * mix(u_vertDeform.offsetBottom, u_vertDeform.offsetTop, uv.y);\n\n  //\n  // Vertex noise\n  //\n\n  float noise = snoise(vec3(\n    noiseCoord.x * u_vertDeform.noiseFreq.x + time * u_vertDeform.noiseFlow,\n    noiseCoord.y * u_vertDeform.noiseFreq.y,\n    time * u_vertDeform.noiseSpeed + u_vertDeform.noiseSeed\n  )) * u_vertDeform.noiseAmp;\n\n  // Fade noise to zero at edges\n  noise *= 1.0 - pow(abs(uvNorm.y), 2.0);\n\n  // Clamp to 0\n  noise = max(0.0, noise);\n\n  vec3 pos = vec3(\n    position.x,\n    position.y + tilt + incline + noise - offset,\n    position.z\n  );\n\n  //\n  // Vertex color, to be passed to fragment shader\n  //\n\n  if (u_active_colors[0] == 1.) {\n    v_color = u_baseColor;\n  }\n\n  for (int i = 0; i < u_waveLayers_length; i++) {\n    if (u_active_colors[i + 1] == 1.) {\n      WaveLayers layer = u_waveLayers[i];\n\n      float noise = smoothstep(\n        layer.noiseFloor,\n        layer.noiseCeil,\n        snoise(vec3(\n          noiseCoord.x * layer.noiseFreq.x + time * layer.noiseFlow,\n          noiseCoord.y * layer.noiseFreq.y,\n          time * layer.noiseSpeed + layer.noiseSeed\n        )) / 2.0 + 0.5\n      );\n\n      v_color = blendNormal(v_color, layer.color, pow(noise, 4.));\n    }\n  }\n\n  //\n  // Finish\n  //\n\n  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);\n}",noise:"//\n// Description : Array and textureless GLSL 2D/3D/4D simplex\n//               noise functions.\n//      Author : Ian McEwan, Ashima Arts.\n//  Maintainer : stegu\n//     Lastmod : 20110822 (ijm)\n//     License : Copyright (C) 2011 Ashima Arts. All rights reserved.\n//               Distributed under the MIT License. See LICENSE file.\n//               https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise\n//               https://github.com/stegu/webgl-noise\n//\n\nvec3 mod289(vec3 x) {\n  return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;\n}\n\nvec4 mod289(vec4 x) {\n  return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;\n}\n\nvec4 permute(vec4 x) {\n    return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);\n}\n\nvec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r)\n{\n  return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;\n}\n\nfloat snoise(vec3 v)\n{\n  const vec2  C = vec2(1.0/6.0, 1.0/3.0) ;\n  const vec4  D = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);\n\n// First corner\n  vec3 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yyy) );\n  vec3 x0 =   v - i + dot(i, C.xxx) ;\n\n// Other corners\n  vec3 g = step(x0.yzx, x0.xyz);\n  vec3 l = 1.0 - g;\n  vec3 i1 = min( g.xyz, l.zxy );\n  vec3 i2 = max( g.xyz, l.zxy );\n\n  //   x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xxx;\n  //   x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxx;\n  //   x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxx;\n  //   x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * C.xxx;\n  vec3 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxx;\n  vec3 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyy; // 2.0*C.x = 1/3 = C.y\n  vec3 x3 = x0 - D.yyy;      // -1.0+3.0*C.x = -0.5 = -D.y\n\n// Permutations\n  i = mod289(i);\n  vec4 p = permute( permute( permute(\n            i.z + vec4(0.0, i1.z, i2.z, 1.0 ))\n          + i.y + vec4(0.0, i1.y, i2.y, 1.0 ))\n          + i.x + vec4(0.0, i1.x, i2.x, 1.0 ));\n\n// Gradients: 7x7 points over a square, mapped onto an octahedron.\n// The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 49 (49*6 = 294)\n  float n_ = 0.142857142857; // 1.0/7.0\n  vec3  ns = n_ * D.wyz - D.xzx;\n\n  vec4 j = p - 49.0 * floor(p * ns.z * ns.z);  //  mod(p,7*7)\n\n  vec4 x_ = floor(j * ns.z);\n  vec4 y_ = floor(j - 7.0 * x_ );    // mod(j,N)\n\n  vec4 x = x_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;\n  vec4 y = y_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;\n  vec4 h = 1.0 - abs(x) - abs(y);\n\n  vec4 b0 = vec4( x.xy, y.xy );\n  vec4 b1 = vec4( x.zw, y.zw );\n\n  //vec4 s0 = vec4(lessThan(b0,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;\n  //vec4 s1 = vec4(lessThan(b1,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;\n  vec4 s0 = floor(b0)*2.0 + 1.0;\n  vec4 s1 = floor(b1)*2.0 + 1.0;\n  vec4 sh = -step(h, vec4(0.0));\n\n  vec4 a0 = b0.xzyw + s0.xzyw*sh.xxyy ;\n  vec4 a1 = b1.xzyw + s1.xzyw*sh.zzww ;\n\n  vec3 p0 = vec3(a0.xy,h.x);\n  vec3 p1 = vec3(a0.zw,h.y);\n  vec3 p2 = vec3(a1.xy,h.z);\n  vec3 p3 = vec3(a1.zw,h.w);\n\n//Normalise gradients\n  vec4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(p0,p0), dot(p1,p1), dot(p2, p2), dot(p3,p3)));\n  p0 *= norm.x;\n  p1 *= norm.y;\n  p2 *= norm.z;\n  p3 *= norm.w;\n\n// Mix final noise value\n  vec4 m = max(0.6 - vec4(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2), dot(x3,x3)), 0.0);\n  m = m * m;\n  return 42.0 * dot( m*m, vec4( dot(p0,x0), dot(p1,x1),\n                                dot(p2,x2), dot(p3,x3) ) );\n}",blend:"//\n// https://github.com/jamieowen/glsl-blend\n//\n\n// Normal\n\nvec3 blendNormal(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn blend;\n}\n\nvec3 blendNormal(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendNormal(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Screen\n\nfloat blendScreen(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn 1.0-((1.0-base)*(1.0-blend));\n}\n\nvec3 blendScreen(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendScreen(base.r,blend.r),blendScreen(base.g,blend.g),blendScreen(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendScreen(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendScreen(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Multiply\n\nvec3 blendMultiply(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn base*blend;\n}\n\nvec3 blendMultiply(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendMultiply(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Overlay\n\nfloat blendOverlay(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn base<0.5?(2.0*base*blend):(1.0-2.0*(1.0-base)*(1.0-blend));\n}\n\nvec3 blendOverlay(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendOverlay(base.r,blend.r),blendOverlay(base.g,blend.g),blendOverlay(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendOverlay(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendOverlay(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Hard light\n\nvec3 blendHardLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn blendOverlay(blend,base);\n}\n\nvec3 blendHardLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendHardLight(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Soft light\n\nfloat blendSoftLight(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn (blend<0.5)?(2.0*base*blend+base*base*(1.0-2.0*blend)):(sqrt(base)*(2.0*blend-1.0)+2.0*base*(1.0-blend));\n}\n\nvec3 blendSoftLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendSoftLight(base.r,blend.r),blendSoftLight(base.g,blend.g),blendSoftLight(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendSoftLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendSoftLight(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Color dodge\n\nfloat blendColorDodge(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn (blend==1.0)?blend:min(base/(1.0-blend),1.0);\n}\n\nvec3 blendColorDodge(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendColorDodge(base.r,blend.r),blendColorDodge(base.g,blend.g),blendColorDodge(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendColorDodge(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendColorDodge(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Color burn\n\nfloat blendColorBurn(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn (blend==0.0)?blend:max((1.0-((1.0-base)/blend)),0.0);\n}\n\nvec3 blendColorBurn(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendColorBurn(base.r,blend.r),blendColorBurn(base.g,blend.g),blendColorBurn(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendColorBurn(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendColorBurn(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Vivid Light\n\nfloat blendVividLight(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn (blend<0.5)?blendColorBurn(base,(2.0*blend)):blendColorDodge(base,(2.0*(blend-0.5)));\n}\n\nvec3 blendVividLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendVividLight(base.r,blend.r),blendVividLight(base.g,blend.g),blendVividLight(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendVividLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendVividLight(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Lighten\n\nfloat blendLighten(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn max(blend,base);\n}\n\nvec3 blendLighten(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendLighten(base.r,blend.r),blendLighten(base.g,blend.g),blendLighten(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendLighten(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendLighten(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Linear burn\n\nfloat blendLinearBurn(float base, float blend) {\n\t// Note : Same implementation as BlendSubtractf\n\treturn max(base+blend-1.0,0.0);\n}\n\nvec3 blendLinearBurn(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\t// Note : Same implementation as BlendSubtract\n\treturn max(base+blend-vec3(1.0),vec3(0.0));\n}\n\nvec3 blendLinearBurn(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendLinearBurn(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Linear dodge\n\nfloat blendLinearDodge(float base, float blend) {\n\t// Note : Same implementation as BlendAddf\n\treturn min(base+blend,1.0);\n}\n\nvec3 blendLinearDodge(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\t// Note : Same implementation as BlendAdd\n\treturn min(base+blend,vec3(1.0));\n}\n\nvec3 blendLinearDodge(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendLinearDodge(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}\n\n// Linear light\n\nfloat blendLinearLight(float base, float blend) {\n\treturn blend<0.5?blendLinearBurn(base,(2.0*blend)):blendLinearDodge(base,(2.0*(blend-0.5)));\n}\n\nvec3 blendLinearLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {\n\treturn vec3(blendLinearLight(base.r,blend.r),blendLinearLight(base.g,blend.g),blendLinearLight(base.b,blend.b));\n}\n\nvec3 blendLinearLight(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {\n\treturn (blendLinearLight(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));\n}",fragment:"varying vec3 v_color;\n\nvoid main() {\n  vec3 color = v_color;\n  if (u_darken_top == 1.0) {\n    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution.xy;\n    color.g -= pow(st.y + sin(-12.0) * st.x, u_shadow_power) * 0.4;\n  }\n  gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n}"},this.conf={presetName:"",wireframe:!1,density:[.06,.16],zoom:1,rotation:0,playing:!0},document.querySelectorAll("canvas").length<1?console.log("DID NOT LOAD HERO STRIPE CANVAS"):(this.minigl=new MiniGl(this.el,null,null,!0),requestAnimationFrame((()=>{this.el&&(this.computedCanvasStyle=getComputedStyle(this.el),this.waitForCssVars())})))}disconnect(){this.scrollObserver&&(window.removeEventListener("scroll",this.handleScroll),window.removeEventListener("mousedown",this.handleMouseDown),window.removeEventListener("mouseup",this.handleMouseUp),window.removeEventListener("keydown",this.handleKeyDown),this.scrollObserver.disconnect()),window.removeEventListener("resize",this.resize)}initMaterial(){this.uniforms={u_time:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:0}),u_shadow_power:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:5}),u_darken_top:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:""===this.el.dataset.jsDarkenTop?1:0}),u_active_colors:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:this.activeColors,type:"vec4"}),u_global:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:{noiseFreq:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:[this.freqX,this.freqY],type:"vec2"}),noiseSpeed:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:5e-6})},type:"struct"}),u_vertDeform:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:{incline:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:Math.sin(this.angle)/Math.cos(this.angle)}),offsetTop:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:-.5}),offsetBottom:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:-.5}),noiseFreq:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:[3,4],type:"vec2"}),noiseAmp:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:this.amp}),noiseSpeed:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:10}),noiseFlow:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:3}),noiseSeed:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:this.seed})},type:"struct",excludeFrom:"fragment"}),u_baseColor:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:this.sectionColors[0],type:"vec3",excludeFrom:"fragment"}),u_waveLayers:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:[],excludeFrom:"fragment",type:"array"})};for(let e=1;e<this.sectionColors.length;e+=1)this.uniforms.u_waveLayers.value.push(new this.minigl.Uniform({value:{color:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:this.sectionColors[e],type:"vec3"}),noiseFreq:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:[2+e/this.sectionColors.length,3+e/this.sectionColors.length],type:"vec2"}),noiseSpeed:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:11+.3*e}),noiseFlow:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:6.5+.3*e}),noiseSeed:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:this.seed+10*e}),noiseFloor:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:.1}),noiseCeil:new this.minigl.Uniform({value:.63+.07*e})},type:"struct"}));return this.vertexShader=[this.shaderFiles.noise,this.shaderFiles.blend,this.shaderFiles.vertex].join("\n\n"),new this.minigl.Material(this.vertexShader,this.shaderFiles.fragment,this.uniforms)}initMesh(){this.material=this.initMaterial(),this.geometry=new this.minigl.PlaneGeometry,this.mesh=new this.minigl.Mesh(this.geometry,this.material)}shouldSkipFrame(e){return!!window.document.hidden||!this.conf.playing||parseInt(e,10)%2==0||void 0}updateFrequency(e){this.freqX+=e,this.freqY+=e}toggleColor(e){this.activeColors[e]=0===this.activeColors[e]?1:0}showGradientLegend(){this.width>this.minWidth&&(this.isGradientLegendVisible=!0,document.body.classList.add("isGradientLegendVisible"))}hideGradientLegend(){this.isGradientLegendVisible=!1,document.body.classList.remove("isGradientLegendVisible")}init(){this.initGradientColors(),this.initMesh(),this.resize(),requestAnimationFrame(this.animate),window.addEventListener("resize",this.resize)}waitForCssVars(){if(this.computedCanvasStyle&&-1!==this.computedCanvasStyle.getPropertyValue("--gradient-color-1").indexOf("#"))this.init(),this.addIsLoadedClass();else{if(this.cssVarRetries+=1,this.cssVarRetries>this.maxCssVarRetries)return this.sectionColors=[16711680,16711680,16711935,65280,255],void this.init();requestAnimationFrame((()=>this.waitForCssVars()))}}initGradientColors(){this.sectionColors=["--gradient-color-1","--gradient-color-2","--gradient-color-3","--gradient-color-4"].map((e=>{let n=this.computedCanvasStyle.getPropertyValue(e).trim();if(4===n.length){const e=n.substr(1).split("").map((e=>e+e)).join("");n=`#${e}`}return n&&`0x${n.substr(1)}`})).filter(Boolean).map(normalizeColor)}}const gradient=new Gradient;gradient.initGradient("#gradient-canvas");
```

```css
#gradient-canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    --gradient-color-1: #c3e4ff; 
    --gradient-color-2: #6ec3f4; 
    --gradient-color-3: #eae2ff;  
    --gradient-color-4: #b9beff;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="gradient-canvas" data-transition-in> </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks for the help. `<canvas id="gradient-canvas" data-transition-in> </canvas>` was not in the `<body>` and set up the .js file in the wrong way.

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept my answer, which contains this solution instead of putting this as an additional answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).